# How can I add my Facebook friends in Waze?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm trying to add my Facebook friends to my Waze account and they are not showing up.

This is my screen, and it never changes

[image]

I found [in their forums](https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=53886) that this is a common problem, but I'm yet to find a solution after trying every workaround that's recommended.

- I disconnected and re-connected Waze to Facebook multiple times.
- I removed the app from Facebook and re-authorized it when it asked me for permissions.
- I signed out and removed all information from Facebook from my iPhone, and signed in again (*)
- I tried downloading Waze on an iPad and link Facebook from there, but the issue is the same.
- I search in [their home page](http://www.waze.com) to login and associated from there, but it only shows you a dashboard with little data.

(*) This step is specifically recommended in their official support "wiki"

[image]

<sub>sorry I can't link directly, it's in an iFrame. You can go to https://www.waze.com/support/question and search for *can't see facebook friends*</sub>

I am willing to completely delete my account (with Waze) and start from scratch, but I assume I'd need to create a new Facebook profile as I cannot find where to completely wipe my association with Facebook (this I don't want to do)

If anyone has any other suggestions, or knows how to completely delete your account in Waze, or whatever steps you can think of, I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem (I'm on an iPhone 5) and just fixed it. I connected Waze to my Facebook account - setting my privacy level at 'My Facebook Friends' - and then went into Settings > Facebook > 'Update Contacts.' That took a few seconds, but when I went back to Waze all my Facebook friends had magically appeared. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think we need to wait until friends on facebook make a movement with their waze.